# ServiceNow: Customized landscape PDF files using 'GeneralPDF' script include

Tags: pdf, scripting, servicenow

I've found a way that utilizes a script include called 'GeneralPDF' to create custom PDF files on the server side, typically the code looks like this:

```
var emptyPDFDoc = new GeneralPDF.Document(null, null, null, null, null, null);

var pdfFile = new GeneralPDF(emptyPDFDoc);   

pdfFile.startHTMLParser();

pdfFile.addHTML("some html");

pdfFile.stopHTMLParser();
```

This is working fine for me, the only thing is that I want to generate the PDF as landscape and I can't, I know that it's possible because the original library looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there is a parameter 'landscape', I've tried passing true but it does not work, any ideas? since the library is utilizing iText at the end I guess it will be sth related to the page size object (new iTextPDFUtil.PageSize()), note that I can extend this library abd write my own version of it in case we need any changes to the core

**Update:**
There is a script include 'GeneralForm' which is an example for utilizing these PDF components, the example says there is a way to set the orientation but it does not specify how !!
[image]

Comment: I navigated through the code and it should allow you to set landscape to `true` like you tried, but `iTextPDFUtil` is mostly a wrapper for `GeneralFormJava` which is a wrapper for `SNC` and don't have access to that. Is there an error in the *System Log*?

Comment: I've checked all types of logs, no errors at all :(

Comment: I'm sure that there is a way but it's not documented, even the 'GeneralForm' example says it's possible but it does not say how (please check the OP edit)

Comment: @Kirk any suggestions?

Comment: I don't believe it will help you, but you can set the orientation on `GeneralPDF.Document` directly in an answer below. Based on the code in that object, setting it to `true` in the constructor will work.If I find anything else I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use the `setLandscape` method for this.

```
emptyPDFDoc.setLandscape(true);
```

Something like this

```
var emptyPDFDoc = new GeneralPDF.Document(null, null, null, null, null, null);
emptyPDFDoc.setLandscape(true);

var pdfFile = new GeneralPDF(emptyPDFDoc);   
pdfFile.startHTMLParser();
pdfFile.addHTML("some html");
pdfFile.stopHTMLParser();
```

Looking at the code for the object looks like you should just be able to do this without the explicit call to `setLandscape`.

```
var emptyPDFDoc = new GeneralPDF.Document(true, null, null, null, null, null);

var pdfFile = new GeneralPDF(emptyPDFDoc);   
pdfFile.startHTMLParser();
pdfFile.addHTML("some html");
pdfFile.stopHTMLParser();
```

Also since this is not documented anywhere, see if you can set this to `landscape`

```
var emptyPDFDoc = new GeneralPDF.Document('landscape', null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help but unfortunately nothing worked :( I even tried passing landscape related keywords like 'landscape', 'a4-landscape' ... and nothing worked :D this can't be solved I guess until some one from the development team responds

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the script include to take account for the `landscape` parameter? It looks like it's hard-coded as being `false` and completely ignoring the parameter, but you might be able to change it like this:

```
this.landscape = false;
```

to the below:

```
this.landscape = landscape || false;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dylan, actually this is not needed because they have built it in another way, initialization happens in this statement `this.landscape = false` and there is another condition statement after few lines that checks whether sth is passed or not and assigns the value accordingly, also  there is another function `setLandscape` that sets the value. nothing works after all :D